# Get Rally Workspace Prefixes through the API

Tags: rally

Does anyone know if there is a way to query the workspace prefixes through the API? I would like to kow what the prefix is for User Stories (normally US), Test Cases (TC) etc for doing searching through source code check ins to then associate the checkin with the appropriate item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is available by querying the TypeDefinition type and including IDPrefix in your fetch.